# Lifting a pipe to work on tuples

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I need a function with type `Pipe a b m r -> Pipe (a, c) (b, c) m r`.

But no matter how much I play with `for`, `~>` or `>~`; I can not match the types properly.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible in general. Suppose we did manage to write it:

```
hypotheticalLift :: Pipe a b m r -> Pipe (a, c) (b, c) m r
```

What behavior should `hypotheticalLift (yield b)` have? Presumably it should be the same as `yield (b, c)` for some `c` -- but which `c`, and why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your point. I was expecting `hypotheticalLift` to just pass the second argument of the tuple as-is. It does not need to generate `c`, just like `Control.Arrow.first`.

Comment: That means it would have to consume one `c` from upstream for each `c` sent downstream. When you want to `yield` a `b`, do you put it into a queue that might become arbitrarily large until `await`ing an `a` gives you a `c` as a side effect, or do you immediately `await` and put the `a` into a queue until you need it? When you `await` an `a`, do you put the accompanying `c` into a queue that might become arbitrarily large?

Comment: @Gurkenglas , oh, now I understand that. Thank you.